# Criterion for Auto-Awarding Bounties

Tags: feature-request

I recently found myself in the situation where I answered a [question with a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968316/groupwise-sorting-in-pandas/49968504#49968504) but the bounty was not automatically awarded. The reason is that the OP started the bounty after I wrote my "first version". My first version was not addressing the OP's question, which became clear after he clarified his question. After several edits, my answer does however do so, as evidenced by six upvotes as of now.

Nevertheless, to get the bounty, it seems that I should have deleted my initial answer and posted a new one. This was a) neither obvious nor intuitive to me, and it may not be obvious to many others, and b) it is very difficult to see why this would be the desired behavior. However, had I deleted my answer and written a new one, I would have 150 reputation points more now. I have a hard time to see why deleting my answers instead of editing them would be preferable from a community perspective.

I understand that there might be reason to exclude "old" answers from being awarded. For instance, if someone adds a bounty to a question to which answers exist, it probably means that these answers do not in fact answer the OP's question. Otherwise, he or she would not add a bounty, and auto-awarding the bounty to these answers would defeat the purpose. However, most people simply edit their answers, and I do not see the intuition why heavily edited answers should be excluded from being awarded the bounty in case the OP fails to log in and to nominate an answer automatically.

If you are worried about people gaming the system by making minor edits, then why not just count the upvotes after the bounty was added, for all answers that were added or edited after the bounty was added? The reality of SO is that answering a question is an iterative process, often involving several clarifications from the OP, which makes several edits necessary to provide high-quality answers. Punishing edited high-quality answers and "early starters" by excluding them from bounties (for instance when added after the initial post) just because they tried to help early in the process seems counterproductive.

To give an example, here is the situation I have in mind:

**Original Poster: 2018-12-25 12:00:00:**

> Hey, can someone show me how to sort a vector like vec <- c(1,3,2)?

**Helpful user: 2018-12-25 12:01:00:**

> Sure. How about sort(vec)

**Original Poster: 2018-12-25 12:02:00:**

> Oh, that does not answer my question. Maybe I forgot to mention I need
>   this in Python, even though my example was in R. Guess my example
>   wasn't so great. HAHA. My bad, sorry. Also, it should not be in any
>   natural sort order, but it should be defined by the following
>   arbitrary logic: bla bla bla. Did I not mention this in the beginning?
>   HAHA, my bad. Sorry. Also, let me add a bounty of 150 points to my
>   question.

**Helpful user: 2018-12-25 13:00:00:**

> Oh, wow. That is quite different then, but I think I can answer this,
>   and since you added a bounty, I will show you not one, not two, but
>   five different ways of doing this. I will spend a considerable amount of
>   time writing this up for you as an edit to my original answer, but here we go: bla bla bla

**Other users: 2018-12-25 13:01:00:**

> Wow, look at let answer by helpful user. Seems solid. Let's upvote it
>   six times.

**Original Poster: 2018-12-25 13:02:00:**

> Great, all these five different ways of doing it that you showed me
>   work. However, I hate typing and really want to have a solution where
>   I don't have to type more than 10 characters. Also, your solution
>   takes two milliseconds to run. I would prefer half a millisecond. So I
>   am not going to accept your answer and wait to see if a better one
>   comes along. I will just log off now and contemplate life for the next
>   year. Catch you lada!

And one week later, no one came up with a better answer that was upvoted at least twice and the bounty vanishes into oblivion just because my initial answer came before the user added a bounty. Had I deleted my initial answer and written a new one, I would have received it. But why would that be the desired behaviour?

I therefore propose that the rule for auto-awarding is being changed. Answers that were edited after the bounty was awarded should not be excluded from the auto-award mechanism.

Comment: Surely you are missing the point of a bounty?  When somebody puts one on a question that you've already answered then he's implicitly signaling that the answer did not help him and he needs others.  Reposting the exact same answer is just going to get him ticked-off badly.  Avoid using pitch-forks when providing help.

Comment: @HansPassant please read my post more carefully. Your objection misses a crucial point I am making. The initial answer is often not the final answer because the OP keeps clarifying his question. Just because someone is trying to help "early" should not automatically exclude him.

Comment: I don't see it.  Are you saying you'd write a completely different answer now that it has a bounty?  What could be the point of that?

Comment: Often the first responses are not answering the OP's question because the question is unclear. Say the OP clarifies his question and simultaneously adds a bounty. I adjust my answer according to the OP's clarification, but since I tried to help early (before the OP clarified his question and added the bounty) I disqualify for the bounty? This seems weird. This is the point I made in my very first paragragh, by the way.

Comment: The universal guidance provided by many meta posts is to not answer unclear questions but post a comment to ask for clarification.  And where applicable to roll back edits that invalidate an existing correct answer.

Comment: While this may be true in some cases (and I am often asking for clarifiation in comments), sometimes a question seems solvable because of the OP did not explain his problem clearly enough, for instance by giving a bad example. Why should I not edit these answers after the OP has clarified his problem? Why should I delete my answer and post a completely new one?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to just do a silly edit to take the bounty to abuse that new rule? Granted, in some specific scenarios, but still

Answer (score 3):

The auto-award system is intended as a fallback measure for cases when the person offering the bounty decided that they didn't get what they were looking for. The purpose of the auto-award system is to reward quality content which was attracted by the bounty.

Your answer was not attracted by the bounty; it was always there. You didn't choose to write that answer because of the bounty. So why should you be auto-awarded it?

It should be understood that your case is an extreme outlier. The person asking the question wrote a Schrodinger's Question: your attempt to answer it caused it to change. The person asking the question also choose not to award you or anybody else the bounty.

This particular collection of circumstances is not sufficiently common to employ complex rules (like deciding how "extreme" changes need to be to quality) to handle. The auto-award system works adequately well in most cases.

Comment: You are right that I do not need bounties to answer questions. However, the extent of my edits to provide an answer to the OP's question in case the OP clarifies his question and thus changes their nature is definitely guided by the bounty.